# Plotly.js only one plot working when using multiple plots on same page

Tags: javascript, plot, polymer, plotly

I'm trying to use **Plotly** to display **multiple plots on the same page** in my **Polymer application**.

Here you can see, how I add the plots:

```
var layout = {
    hovermode: 'closest',
    title: title,
    xaxis: {
        title: title,
        titlefont: {
            family: 'Arial, monospace',
            size: 20,
            color: '#7f7f7f'
        }
    },
    yaxis: {
        title: 'Trigger rate',
        titlefont: {
            family: 'Arial',
            size: 20,
            color: '#7f7f7f'
        }
    }
};


for(var i=0; i<25; i++) {

    var data = [{
        x: xtime,
        y: yrate,
        name: 'DM'+i,
        text: hints,
        type: 'Scatter+Lines'

    }];

    cname="plot"+i;
    appendDiv(cname);
    Plotly.newPlot(cname, data, layout, {showLink: false});

}
```

All of the plots are displayed correctly. But all the "**functions**" of Plotly like zooming or save as image do **only work for the last plot**. Same for the information on hovering.

I searched on several pages, but did not find a solution.

There is an issue on github with the same problem when using ioslides presentations. But I don't use isoslides.
https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/463

Does someone know, how to use multiple plotly plots on the same page with all the functionality?

thank you

Comment: What is cname? Is it possible that you create new plots but they all refer to the same object?

Comment: cname is the variable with the id (a.ex. plot1, plot2)

Comment: It works perfectly fine with vanilla JS. Can you add a fiddle with your polymer code?

Comment: Is `appendDiv` your own function? If show, please display it. Also, we don't have your data to play with. Can you make a fiddle? Incidentally, I have no trouble making multiple plots on a page.  http://plnkr.co/edit/mtHNWF4zTBBivmRDnwY2?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this example help?

HTML:

```
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
  <script data-require="plotly@1.0.0" data-semver="1.0.0" src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js" defer></script>
  <script src="script.js" defer></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
var layout = 
{
    width: 500,
    height: 400,
    hovermode: 'closest',
    title: "title",
    xaxis: {
        title: "X",
        titlefont: {
            family: 'Arial, monospace',
            size: 20,
            color: '#7f7f7f'
        }
  },
  yaxis: {
      title: 'Y',
      titlefont: {
          family: 'Arial',
          size: 20,
          color: '#7f7f7f'
      }
  }
};

var x_vals = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
  x_vals.push(i);
}

function makeYVals(x)
{
    var y_vals = x.map(function(x)
  {
    return 2 + 1.3*x + (1 - 2*Math.random());
  });

  return y_vals;
}

for (var graph_num = 0 ; graph_num < 3; graph_num++)
{
  var graph_div = document.createElement("div");
  graph_div.id = "graph-" + graph_num;
  document.body.appendChild(graph_div);

  console.log(graph_div.id);

  var y_vals = makeYVals(x_vals);

  var data = 
  {
    x: x_vals,
    y: y_vals,
    mode: 'lines+markers',
    type: 'scatter'
  };

  layout.title = "Graph " + graph_num;

  console.log(data);

  Plotly.newPlot(graph_div, [data], layout);
}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/XluyqzOLOYAtdzp9EevX?p=preview

Comment: Hey @abaltar, I had a pretty similar problem which i was not able to solve even with your example. If you dont mind pls have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75017078/plotly-js-multiple-plots-created-only-last-one-is-working-as-intended