# plotly.js Multiple plots created, only last one is working as intended

Tags: javascript, plotly, plotly.js

If I click on a symbol on a map I want to create timeseries-plots with plotly. If i click on the next symbol there should be a new plot etc.
This is working fine, but I am not able to use the plotly interface in the first plots again.

I build a jfiddle that shows my problem and my code:

```
var treediv_ids = [-1];

var timeseries_div_HTML = function(id) {
  var ts_div_html_vis =
    "<div class='ts_con_vis' id='ts_data_" + id + "'>\n\
                <div class='ts_data_div' name='ts_data_div" + id + "' id='ts_data_div_" + id + "_env'></div>"
  treediv_ids.push(id);
  return ts_div_html_vis;
};

var addTS = function() {
  // Create the subdivs for timeseries_production
  var new_id = Math.max(...treediv_ids) + 1;
  var new_div = timeseries_div_HTML(new_id);

  $('#timeseriescontainer').html($('#timeseriescontainer').html() + new_div);
  // Create timeseries using plotly and local datasets
  // 
  // Environmental Data
  // Create layout object
  var layout_E = {
    title: 'Tim',
    yaxis: {
      title: 'Value'
    },
    margin: {
      t: 40,
      b: 20,
      r: 40,
      l: 40
    },
  }
  plot("ts_data_div_" + new_id + "_env", layout_E);
}


function plot(target_div, layout) {
   var data = [];
  for (var i = 1; i < 3; i++) {
    var randomColor = Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);
    var trace = {
      type: "scatter",
      mode: "lines",
      name: i,
      x: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
      y: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
      line: {
        color: randomColor
      }
    }
    data.push(trace)
  }


  layout.title = layout.title + target_div.slice("ts_data_div_".length);

  target = document.getElementById(target_div);
  Plotly.newPlot(target, data, layout);

}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wmg5k8xn/2/

I found this thread: [Plotly.js only one plot working when using multiple plots on same page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39867224/plotly-js-only-one-plot-working-when-using-multiple-plots-on-same-page)
But I did not understand why it is working in the accepted answer and why it is not working for me.

Edit: my HTML and CSS code:

```
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>


  
  <body>
  
  <button onclick=addTS() style="z-index:100">
    ABC  
  </button>
  
  
  <div id="timeseriescontainer"></div>

  <script data-require="plotly@1.0.0" data-semver="1.0.0" src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js" defer></script>
  <script src="script.js" defer></script>
  </body>

</html>


#timeseriescontainer{
    width:90%;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    right:0px;
    top: 0px;
    background-color: green;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

.ts_con_vis{
    background-color: red;
    width: 99%;
    height: 49%;
    margin-left:5px;
    margin-top:1px;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
}

.ts_data_div{
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is caused by this line:

```
$('#timeseriescontainer').html($('#timeseriescontainer').html() + new_div);
```

Just use native browser functions instead:

```
const container = document.getElementById('timeseriescontainer');
container.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', new_div);
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/qhk7nmsp/

Comment: Exactly! I was posting the same answer, only with jquery's `$('#timeseriescontainer').append(new_div);`

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution. As far as I can tell it is working :-)